# Erro de servidor restful no tomcat

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

Alguém poderia de ajudar um um problema no servidor *REST*?

Estou desenvolvendo um app *android* e estou trabalhando com um servidor *restful*, banco de dados *Postgres* e *Tomcat*.

E estou tendo esse erro quase sempre que faço diversas requisições:

> ```
> GRAVE: 
> Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/Servidor] threw exception 
> [javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Um erro de E/S
> ocorreu ao enviar para o processo do servidor.] 
> with root cause
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> ```

E este erro também:

> ```
> [javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Um erro de E/S
> ocorreu ao enviar para o processo do servidor.] 
> with root cause
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: O seu servidor não consegue conectar no banco de dados. Qual é a URL do banco de dados? Você tem certeza que o banco de dados está rodando corretamente? Se você executar um ping do seu servidor até o IP do seu banco de dados funciona? Tem certeza que algum firewall não está bloqueando conexões entrando na porta do PostgreSQL do banco de dados ou bloqueando conexões saindo do servidor?

Comment: Então, a conexão esta correta, o firewall não esta bloqueando as conexões na porta do PostgreSQL. Estas exceções de java.net.SocketException  e java.net.SocketTimeoutException, acontecem quando envio requisições do app para o servidor, apenas neste cenário. @VictorStafusa

Comment: Bem, a mensagem deixa bem clara que uma `JDBCConnectionException` ocorre no `Servlet.service()`. Ou seja, o servidor tentando falar com o banco de dados. Isso dá a entender fortemente que o problema está no servidor, e não no app.

Comment: Sim, isso esta claro mesmo. Você teria alguma dica? Pois estou iniciando em java e é a primeira vez que tomo esse erro. @VictorStafusa

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes sobre o seu código e sobre o erro obtido?